# Am I interacting with other players if I don't have PS Plus?

Tags: let-it-die

I'm playing Let It Die with an internet connection, but no Playstation Plus account. I've been given access to the Tokyo Death Metro with a list of possible raids and I'm fighting Haters in the Tower, but I'm curious if these characters are just procedurally generated or if I'm actually interacting with other games online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in game [FAQ](http://www.letitdiethegame.com/support.html), there is no information, that you require PS Plus to interact with other players. Still, can't say, that anyone in the game is directly interacting with other games/gamers, since, unlike DS/Bloodborne, game features async multiplayer. But all haters are actually another player's characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you live in the UK, you'll need to have PlayStation Plus to download the game, much less play. Everywhere else you do not need PlayStation Plus to play. Mind you, if you do have PlayStation Plus, there's a freebie bundle that you can download once to give your characters some items.

As far as Haters go, none of them are procedurally generated. There are, however, "developer Haters," which I believe only show up when you reach a certain star-level of character. (You start with a 1-star character, and you eventually earn the ability to purchase characters all the way up to 6 stars.)

You can tell when you're fighting developer haters because the names above their heads will start with "YTYMk-" and then end in a number; otherwise you'll be fighting other players' characters.